# How can I find true date for my table on oracle sql

Tags: date, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have two tables.
TABLE A:

[image]

TABLE B:

[image]

I need to find which TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID on TABLE B should I use for TARIFE_ID for my TABLE A.
For example;
on TABLE B there are two different TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID for TARIFE_ID=10168822.
First TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID begin 1.01.2012 and we can use this TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID until 10.07.2023 and then we should use 10336850.
So for TABLE A;
for TARIFE_ID=10168822, I want to put 10313919 TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID because between 17.05.2023 and 22.05.2023 TABLE B has this TARIFE_GECERLIK_ID

I want to see my new table like this:

[image]
Can you help me?

Comment: Please include your desired output.

Comment: I added thank you so much @TimBiegeleisen